# Embedding *.ttc fonts using PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox, truetype

PDFBox provides mechanisms to embed various types of fonts. For example, it provides `PDTrueTypeFont.loadTTF(...)`, which can accept a TrueType (*.ttf) file.

The TrueType Collection format (*.ttc) supports multiple fonts per file, in an extension of the TrueType format.

Attempting to load a *.ttc file with `PDTrueTypeFont.loadTTF()` results in an IOException being thrown.

How does one embed one or all of the fonts in a *.ttc file into a PDF document, using PDFBox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PDF specification doesn't allow for TrueType collections as embedded fonts. You'll need to pull out a single TTF-format stream from the *.ttc and embed that.

As it stands (and AFAIK) PDFBox doesn't support this by itself; I used Google's 'sfntly' [package.](http://code.google.com/p/sfntly/)

Quick and dirty solution:

```
FontFactory factory = FontFactory.getInstance();
Font[] fonts = factory.loadFonts( ... ); // pulls every TTF out of TTC
ArrayList<PDTrueTypeFont> pdf_fonts = new ArrayList<PDTrueTypeFont>();
for( Font f : fonts ){
   // sfntly writes each font to a TTF stream
   ByteArrayOutputStream out = ByteArrayOutputStream();
   factory.serializeFont(f, out);

   // PDFBox reads the stream and embeds the font
   ByteArrayInputStream ttf_font_stream = ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
   pdf_fonts.add(PDTrueTypeFont.loadTTF(document, ttf_font_stream));
}
```

`Font` and `FontFactory` are in `com.google.typography.sfntly`

Java code not guaranteed to be 100% correct; been working in Clojure a lot lately....

Comment: Thanks! That looks good. Can I get the font names from the *.ttc file with sfntly? And do you happen to known if getting the names of the sfntly Fonts require parsing the rest of the font?

Comment: You *can* get the name out with sfntly; it's not exactly "simple" though. You need to `getTable(Tag.name)` to get an instance of `NameTable`. You can access names from there with `.getNameEntry`, but you have to pass in appropriate constants. That will give you access to a slew of "names" for the font.  You're probably safest by iterating through the `NameTable` and pulling the first entry with a `FontFamilyName` or `PreferredFamily` as its `nameId`.

Comment: ... and unfortunately, yes; when you build the sfntly `Font`s it parses the entire sfnt wrapper, however you can make it parse *less* if you need to by using `FontFactory.loadFontsForBuilding` (which gives a list of `Font.Builder` objects; you can then strip these down to just parse the `name` table. Then you call `.build()` on the builder objects to produce a `Font` object you can poke around in.

Comment: For the name I found example code in SFLint.java, which uses the constants `NameId.FontFamilyName` and `NameId.FullFontName`. I'll look at `PreferredFamily` as well. And thank you for the suggestion of `FontFactory.loadFontsForBuilding()`. Your excellent answers deserve more votes.

Comment: This seems to fail for *.ttc at least on the Mac. 1PDTrueTypeFont.loadTTF()1 throws an NPE after some code that sets a variable iff it finds a table whose platform ID is CMAPTable.PLATFORM_WINDOWS`. Looks like it might be a bug; I'm going to report it.

Comment: btw pdfbox 2.0.20 features loading of ttc files in a provided example EmbeddedMultipleFonts.java